# Capture specific column from command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I know how to redirect first 5 lines of the output to a file when I execute a command. I want to know how to redirect only specific information from the output.

For example I would like to execute the command "free -m" and redirect the column "used" from the output to a text file.

How to do this without editing the whole output manually?

Comment: So, your question is about _lines_ or about _columns_?

Comment: My question is about extracting from the output only the things that i need.. In that case with "free -m" is to redirect only the column "used".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are more elegant answers but this should work:

```
free -m | awk '{if (NR == 1) {print $2} else {print $3}}' > file.out
```

This command takes the standard output from `free -m` and sends it to `awk`. For the first line, it prints the second column (here, the title of the column of interest), otherwise it prints the third column (the subsequent lines in `free -m` have an extra column).

Comment: Nice, it works. So in general in order to manipulate the output of a command i have to use awk right? If i go learn more about awk will it allow me to extract only a specific line and column? E.g The first two lines in the second column.

Comment: It depends a little on the output. I use awk, used, grep, or a python or perl script. If you are looking for something simple like the third column awk works well. There are of course other ways to do it. I think learning a little awk will be very helpful for these types of extractions.